How can I reset wait/sleep time in rust?
My program is intended to listen for key-presses(vol, brightness, etc), and show an OSD popup(I use EWW widgets for that) that indicates vol/brightness levels, wait for N milliseconds, and then close the popup.
I figured out how to listen to key-presses and execute shell commands.
Here's almost what it looks like when you press the volume-down key:
if event.event_type == KeyPress(VOL_DN) {
    osd_open("osd-vol");
    //wait for N milliseconds;
    osd_close("osd-vol");
}

I think there's a sleep() function of some sorts? But I think it just stops the program execution until the wait time is over?
Here's what I'm stuck with:

Waiting for N milliseconds before closing the popup
When you press a key multiple times before closing, the timer should reset to N without closing the popup


For your second question, I would recommend a global handler, or an async solution using tokio: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.abort

Observe that your logic means you always sleep at least N seconds, sometimes more but never less. So start by sleeping for N seconds, and process events meanwhile in another thread. The other thread tracks the time since the last interesting keypress. When N seconds elapse, ask the other thread for the time of the last keypress (call that T) and sleep until again until time T+N

You can use for your 1st question the thread sleep like this:
use std::{thread, time};

let ten_millis = time::Duration::from_millis(10);
let now = time::Instant::now();

if event.event_type == KeyPress(VOL_DN) {
    osd_open("osd-vol");
    //wait for N milliseconds;
    thread::sleep(ten_millis);
    osd_close("osd-vol");
}

